# Getting typescript error in Nextjs 14 sitemap in array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I made `sitemap.tsx` in the `app` router in NextJS 14 and when in try to make an array of routers for example:

```js
const contacts =
    NavContacts?.filter((val) => {
      if (
        !val.name.includes("Form") 
      ) {
        return val;
      }
    }).map((design) => {
      return {
        url: `${siteUrl}/contact${design.link}`,
        lastModified: new Date(),
        changeFrequency: "weekly",
        priority: 0.8,
      };
    }) || [];
```

but when I return the array in the `sitemap()` function I got the error in the `contact` function.

here is the full code:

```js
import { allProtoDesigns, allProtoWebs } from "contentlayer/generated";
import { NavContacts } from "@/lib/NavContact";
import { MetadataRoute } from "next";

type sitemap = {
  url: String,
  lastModified: Date,
  changefreq: String,
  priority: Number
}

const GetWeb = () => {
  const doc = allProtoWebs;
  return doc;
};

const GetDesign = () => {
  const doc = allProtoDesigns;
  return doc;
};

export default function sitemap(): MetadataRoute.Sitemap {
  const siteUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN_URL || 'http://localhost:3000';
  const web = GetWeb();
  const designs = GetDesign();

  const allWeb =
    web?.map((web) => {
      return {
        url: `${siteUrl}${web.slug}`,
        lastModified: new Date(),
        changeFrequency: "weekly",
        priority: 0.8,
      };
    }) || [];

  const allDesing =
    designs?.map((design) => {
      return {
        url: `${siteUrl}${design.slug}`,
        lastModified: new Date(),
        changeFrequency: "weekly",
        priority: 0.8,
      };
    }) || [];

  const contacts =
    NavContacts?.filter((val) => {
      if (
        !val.name.includes("Form") 
      ) {
        return val;
      }
    }).map((design) => {
      return {
        url: `${siteUrl}/contact${design.link}`,
        lastModified: new Date(),
        changeFrequency: "weekly",
        priority: 0.8,
      };
    }) || [];

  return [
    {
      url: `${siteUrl}`,
      lastModified: new Date(),
      changeFrequency: "yearly",
      priority: 1,
    },
    {
      url: siteUrl + "/portfolio",
      lastModified: new Date(),
      changeFrequency: "weekly",
      priority: 0.8,
    },
    {
      url: siteUrl + "/about",
      lastModified: new Date(),
      changeFrequency: "weekly",
      priority: 0.5,
    },
    {
      url: siteUrl + "/contact",
      lastModified: new Date(),
      changeFrequency: "weekly",
      priority: 0.5,
    },
    // ...allWeb,
    // ...allDesing,
    ...contacts,
  ];
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact error you are getting?

Comment: this is the error @X8inez:
  Types of property 'url' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

Comment: FYI, <changefreq> and <priority> variables are not important for Google anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the following error is TS is expecting a string but the value passed into `url` has the tendency of returning undefined.

> Types of property 'url' are incompatible. Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

For example: `web.slug` in this line  `url:` ${siteUrl}${web.slug}``

You can fix this by modifying the url type as so:

```
type sitemap = {
  url: string | undefined,
  lastModified: Date,
  changefreq: string,
  priority: number
}
```

or

Use the nullish operator `??` to add a default string in the event the value returned is undefined

```
import { allProtoDesigns, allProtoWebs } from "contentlayer/generated";
import { NavContacts } from "@/lib/NavContact";
import { MetadataRoute } from "next";

type sitemap = {
  url: string,
  lastModified: Date,
  changefreq: string,
  priority: number
}

const GetWeb = () => {
  const doc = allProtoWebs;
  return doc;
};

const GetDesign = () => {
  const doc = allProtoDesigns;
  return doc;
};

export default function sitemap(): MetadataRoute.Sitemap {
  const siteUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN_URL || 'http://localhost:3000';
  const web = GetWeb();
  const designs = GetDesign();

  const allWeb =
    web?.map((web) => {
      return {
        url: `${siteUrl}${web.slug ?? ""}`, // here
        lastModified: new Date(),
        changeFrequency: "weekly",
        priority: 0.8,
      };
    }) || [];

  const allDesing =
    designs?.map((design) => {
      return {
        url: `${siteUrl}${design.slug ?? ""}`, // here
        lastModified: new Date(),
        changeFrequency: "weekly",
        priority: 0.8,
      };
    }) || [];

  const contacts =
    NavContacts?.filter((val) => {
      if (
        !val.name.includes("Form") 
      ) {
        return val;
      }
    }).map((design) => {
      return {
        url: `${siteUrl}/contact${design.link ?? ""}`, // here
        lastModified: new Date(),
        changeFrequency: "weekly",
        priority: 0.8,
      };
    }) || [];

  return [
    {
      url: `${siteUrl}`,
      lastModified: new Date(),
      changeFrequency: "yearly",
      priority: 1,
    },
    {
      url: siteUrl + "/portfolio",
      lastModified: new Date(),
      changeFrequency: "weekly",
      priority: 0.8,
    },
    {
      url: siteUrl + "/about",
      lastModified: new Date(),
      changeFrequency: "weekly",
      priority: 0.5,
    },
    {
      url: siteUrl + "/contact",
      lastModified: new Date(),
      changeFrequency: "weekly",
      priority: 0.5,
    },
    // ...allWeb,
    // ...allDesing,
    ...contacts,
  ];
}
```